# Insert table name in cell based on where the data was extracted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm collecting responses from Typeform into google spreadsheet. I have multiple Typeforms but everyone contains the same questions. Each table in the spreadsheet represent each Typeform questionnaire (sort of like an "ID" for each typeform).

Then I have a last table called "Anamnesis" to where i gather the data once a row is updated in any table. In "Anamnesis" I have a script that sends any updated row to mysql database. (I have this last table because I need to transform the answers into readable fluid text).

What I want is to insert the table name from where the data was extracted from to appear in the first cell of "Anamnesis".

[To get an understanding of how I would like to have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J6Tj.png)

Super thankful for any help with this!

**This is the code I've used so far. But I need it to change value based on which table it was inserted from**

```
  if (!idx)
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  else {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var idx = parseInt(idx);
    if (isNaN(idx) || idx < 1 || sheets.length < idx)
      throw "Invalid parameter (it should be a number from 0 to "+sheets.length+")";
    return sheets[idx-1].getName();
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask your question in terms of the scripting.  We're not really interested in what it does for you only in helping you overcome scripting issues.  If you can't ask a more script focused question we probably wont be interested in providing a solution unless we get extremely bored...which is possible but not as likely.

Comment: Ok thanks for helpin a beginner out @Cooper!